# jq command optimization with variable keys. Two separate jq commands combined in one

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a lot of different json files with slightly different structures.

For example, I could access `LASTNAME`'s value in the next json file

```
{
  "Results": [
    {
      "Persons": [
        {
          "id": 20,
          "Position": "office employee",
          "Profession": "Office workers",
          "Address": {
            "City": "Portland",
            "State": "Washington",
            "Country": "USA"
          },
          "PersonalInfo": {
            "LASTNAME": "Pete",
            "FIRSTNAME": "Columb",
            "MIDNAME": "George"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 21,
          "Position": "Manager",
          "Profession": "Medicine",
          "Address": {
            "City": "New York",
            "State": "",
            "Country": "USA"
          },
          "PersonalInfo": {
            "LASTNAME": "Bob",
            "FIRSTNAME": "Smith",
            "MIDNAME": ""
          }
        }
      ],
      "ItemsNumber": 2,
      "AdditionalItems": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

with a command:

```
$ jq -r '. | .Results | .[] | .Persons | .[] | .PersonalInfo | .LASTNAME' question.json
```

Output:

```
Pete
Bob
```

The second json file example (`$ jq -r . question2.json`):

```
{
  "Results": [
    {
      "Persons": [
        {
          "id": 2000,
          "Position": "Director",
          "Profession": "Marketing",
          "Address": {
            "City": "Las Vegas",
            "State": "Nevada",
            "Country": "USA"
          },
          "PersonalInfo": {
            "Name1": "Steven",
            "Name2": "Bond",
            "Name3": ""
          }
        }
      ],
      "ItemsNumber": 1,
      "AdditionalItems": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Command:

```
jq -r '. | .Results | .[] | .Persons | .[] | .PersonalInfo | .Name2' question2.json
```

Output:

```
Bond
```

**Question:**
**Is it possible to combine these two commands in one and make it shorter** (or unique: without `.Results`, `.Persons`, `.PersonalInfo` sections accessing)?

I tried the next, for example, to combine:

```
jq -r '. | .Results | .[] | .Persons | .[] | .PersonalInfo | (.Name2 or .LASTNAME)' question*.json
```

It outputs:

```
true
true
true
```

But I want:

```
Pete
Bob
Bond
```

Number of variable keys could be bigger than two: `LASTNAME`, `lname`, `ThirdName`, `Name2`

**Update**:
I am currently unable to use the second customcommander's command properly to output required values without `"; null; "` lines using `jq` only:

```
cat question*.json | jq '.. | (.Address?|.City) + "; " + (.id|tostring) + "; " + (.PersonalInfo?| .LASTNAME // .Name2) | select(.)'
```

Output is not nice in this case:

```
"; null; "
"; null; "
"Portland; 20; Pete"
"; null; "
"; null; "
"New York; 21; Bob"
"; null; "
"; null; "
"; null; "
"; null; "
"; null; "
"Las Vegas; 2000; Bond"
"; null; "
"; null; "
"; null; "
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you simply need to use the alternative operator `//`

```
. | .Results | .[] | .Persons | .[] | .PersonalInfo | .LASTNAME // .Name2
```

If you need to shorten the syntax you can use:

```
.. | (.LASTNAME? // .Name2?) | select(.)
```

But I'm not sure whether that's either performant or advisable.

Comment: Yes, Thanks (+1). It works! And, also, could this command be shortened somehow.

Comment: The initial `.|` is never needed, and in the present case, all the occurrences of |.[] can be abbreviated to []. In fact, most of the | can be elided.

Answer (score 0):

I've also used peak's suggestion to shorten  a `jq` command for slightly different requirement. I couldn't use the second customcommander's suggestion properly to combine values on different levels of json file:

```
cat question*.json | jq '.Results[].Persons[] | (.Address|.City) + "; " + (.id|tostring) + "; " + (.PersonalInfo| .LASTNAME // .Name2)'
"Portland; 20; Pete"
"New York; 21; Bob"
"Las Vegas; 2000; Bond"
```